# Cannot convert from 'System.Generic.Collection.List'

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I wan't to return List of objects but I get:

> Cannot convert from `'System.Generic.Collection.List<ErrorDashboard_DatabaseEF.parsde_errors>'` to `'ErrorDashboard_DatabaseEF.parsed_errors'`

I was able to return just a single object when using FirstOrDefault(), but I need every object between specified dates.

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetAllLogsWithMatchingHash(string hash)
    {
        using (var repository = new repositoryCollection())
        {
           var result =  repository.ErrorLogsRepository.GetAllLogsByHash("dc03cd92c3fa7f9a647adb9dbf95ab54");
        }
        return Redirect("home");
    }
```

Repository

```
   public List<parsed_errorsModel> GetAllLogsByHash(string hashToSearchBy)
    {
        using (var context = new EdDbContext())
        {
            var dateFromToCheck = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31);
            hashToSearchBy = "969da6814fa518a8fac3a03cc32378fc";
            var result =  context.parsed_errors.OrderByDescending(x=>x.TimeUtc).Where(c => c.TimeUtc > dateFromToCheck && c.HashDetails == hashToSearchBy).ToList();
            return parsed_errorTranslator.TranslateToModel(result); <-- here it where I get the error
        }
    }
```

My translator

```
 internal static parsed_errorsModel TranslateToModel (parsed_errors entity)
    {
        var result =  new parsed_errorsModel()
        {
            ErrorId = entity.ErrorId,
            Application = entity.Application,
            Host = entity.Host,
            Type = entity.Type,
            Source = entity.Source,
            Message = entity.Message,
            User = entity.User,
            StatusCode = entity.StatusCode,
            TimeUtc = entity.TimeUtc,
            Sequence = entity.Sequence,
            AllXml = entity.AllXml,
            Details = entity.Details,
            HashDetails = entity.HashDetails,
            PropertyPath = entity.PropertyPath,
            InternalErrorId = entity.InternalErrorId,
            RequestType = entity.RequestType,


        };
        return result;

    }
```

This request from the same repository works

```
   public parsed_errorsModel GetErrorByTicketId(Guid ticketId)
    {
        using (var context = new EdDbContext())
        {
            var errorToGet = context.parsed_errors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ErrorId.Equals(ticketId));
            return parsed_errorTranslator.TranslateToModel(errorToGet);
        }
    }
```

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it might have been the excess amount of code (only provide minimal reproducible code blocks) as well as the lack of a real identifiable problem. What line of code is the error occuring?  My guess is you're using "var" for everything which is a bad practice. Be explicit in what you are declaring.

Comment: I understand that this amount of code was maybe unnecessary, but I've been downvoted before for not posting enough code. That question was asked before and I have tried all the solutions i've found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code has two issues:

```
return parsed_errorTranslator.TranslateToModel(result);
```

First, `result` is a collection of objects.  But the `TranslateToModel` method expects a single object.  Second, `TranslateToModel` *returns* a single object, but in this method you're expecting to return a collection of objects.

An apple and a basket of apples are two very different things.

It sounds like you want to call `TranslateToModel` on each result from the data, and return the entirety of the collection.  You should be able to do that with something like this:

```
return result.Select(r => parsed_errorTranslator.TranslateToModel(r)).ToList();
```

This would select all elements in `result` (which semantically should probably be called `results` to avoid confusion), call that method on each one, and return the resulting list.

---

One thing to note here... Since you're already calling `.ToList()` on the query before this line of code, all of your records are already in memory so everything you're doing is in code.  This can lead to performance problems with large amounts of data though.  Just tossing around `.ToList()` with LINQ is more of a stop-gap than a solution to things.

While it *may* work in this case just fine, for larger amounts of data it means materializing *all* of that data into memory where a more dynamic approach to querying the backing data may be better.  LINQ to Entities is *really good* at facilitating that dynamic query approach.  However, when translating your expression trees to SQL code (or whatever the backing data is), it won't be able to translate `TranslateToModel()`, since that's custom C#.

Just something to keep in mind going forward, hopefully not an issue here.

Comment: Thanks! that solved all my problems, and I will defiently look in to ToList(); especially if that could bring my app performence up.